# Recommended flow for using Google Wallet with complex custom digital goods

Tags: android-pay

I'm trying to set up a google wallet payment process for users to purchase an entry into a tournament.  In order to do this, the user has to fill out a bunch of information about themselves (name, league player number, contact phone number, etc), and there are some other pieces of data that are implicit, such as a unique identifier for the tournament they're entering.

It seems like there are two ways to accomplish this in Google Wallet, and I'm wondering if I'm missing another, better workflow and/or if one of these two ways is preferred.

**Possibility #1**

When the user clicks the wallet button, I serialize the form and submit it to my server using ajax.  If the form is properly filled out, the server encodes everything about the form into the sellerData field of the JWT, and returns the JWT asynchronously.  I then pass this JWT to wallet, expecting to receive it in my postback handler.

The postback handler then constructs the entry using the information from the JWT sellerData field and records it in the database.

This possibility is intuitive to me, and I've implemented it, but I'm running up against the 200 character limit for the sellerData field, since it contains multiple peoples' names, phone numbers, and various other form elements.  There's just no room.  I don't have a workaround for this, and would welcome thoughts.

This approach has the advantage that nothing is created in my database until payment is successful, but I don't know how to work around the difficulties with representing the entire form in the JWT to get it to the postback handler somehow.

**Possibility #2**

The user just submits the entry form using the normal web-form submission process, which creates something in the database.  Database objects newly created in this way are marked as "unpaid", and are therefore incomplete.

Once the user successfully creates their entry in the database, they are then presented with a *second* page at which they can pay.  This works better because I can now just put the database key for the object they just created into the sellerData field, and not worry about the size limit.

It does have the unfortunate side-effect of having these half-completed objects in the database, as well as running the risk of users not quite understanding the two-step register-and-then-pay process, and forgetting to pay.  I'd have to be quite careful and proactive about making sure that users realize that A) it's okay to submit the form with no payment information, and B) that submitting the first form doesn't mean that they're done.

Thoughts?

Comment: Some thoughts: In Option 1 - What about a unique identifier for user "profile" info (so you minimize data sent to Google) - persisted in your scope for that "payment session"? I realize this is like Option 2, so if db isn't preferred (at this stage), client side? In Option 2, unclear why the extra step (seems there is no need for the "pay step"). Maybe its not so bad to have data on "abandoned carts" (re: half-completed objects)? Hth...

Answer (score 2):

I think Option 2 is a pretty standard buy flow.  Step 1 enter in your information Step 2 confirm your information and pay with Wallet.

The onsuccess callback could then redirect the user to a purchase receipt page.

My consumer mind doesn't see any purchase flow red flags.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up going with option 2, because it was simplest for me and I didn't think it would confuse users.

I missed a third option, though, which is that I could allow people to buy a blank entry form and then fill it out after purchase.  I think this might have even been better; it matches the in-person buying experience better and would therefore be more familiar to purchasers, and it avoids the problem of people who think they've registered but somehow didn't realize that they had to pay.